# MongoDB comparison

Tags: database, mongodb, express

I am trying to retrieve data in my MongoDB database. If I have the following below in my mongoDB database, I want to select the Password given the Username. So in this case, I will be looking through the database for a Username that is 'e' and retrieving the password associated with that specific Username. I've tried looking everywhere but I can't seem to find a solution on how to do it. I am using express, node, and mongoDB for this personal project. What I have so far is just looking up with database with .find({ Username: Username} and it outputs the entire JSON object.

To clarify, I will be sending a request with a Username of value 'e' and looking it up the database trying to retrieve the value of Password.

```
{
    _id: 62d7712e6d6732706b46094e,
    Username: 'e',
    Password: 'hi',
    __v: 0
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

find takes multiple inputs you can give the select statements also in find itself

so the query will be like

`db.collectionName.find({username:'e'},{_id:0,password:1})`

mongo by default fetch _id all the time by default so you need to specifically mention to not fetch _id thus _id :0

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I managed to get [ { Password: 'hi' } ], but how would I only extract the value so that it becomes "hi". Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

for such scenarios, there are 2 options if username is unique i would suggest to go with findOne rather then find

`db.collectionName.findOne({username:'e'}).password`

the same will work if you have multiple records with same username but you want only the first record

but if you want data of all the records as array

`db.collectionName.find({username:'e'},{_id:0,password:1})..map( function(u) { return u.password; } )`